# Get value from subject in nginit

Tags: angular, observable

I need some values from a service with an http call so I save them in a subject.

This works fine in my component with

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.values.subscribe(values) {
        console.log(values);
    }
}
```

But when I the `ngOnInit` will be fired again I don't get any values because the service is only triggered when the whole website is reloaded (not when I switch to another page).

So how is it possible to subscribe to elements when they change but also get them when they are already inside the subject?

Comment: Can't make any sense of this part "But when I the ngOnInit will be fired again"

Comment: What does "the service is only triggered" mean?

Comment: In my AppComponent I call the service to fill the subject. When I switch the page to another one that also subscribed to the values in the service it won't be triggered because nothing changed to them.

Comment: Then using a `BehaviorSubject` should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is to use a `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` (without initial value) which returns the last emitted value to new subscribers.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work but I need default values to init the subject. It would be cool if it would wait until something is inside the `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: Then a `ReplaySubject` might be a better fit https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md (". If you are looking for BehaviorSubject without initial value see Rx.ReplaySubject.")